# Malloc: How to forcefully free the memory indicated by mallinfo fordblks

Tags: linux, malloc

My application frees up a huge chunk of memory on receiving a particular event. Here is the mallinfo stats before the event.

```
INFO  sas2    - Total non-mmapped bytes (arena):       181747712
INFO  sas2    - # of free chunks (ordblks):            14340
INFO  sas2    - # of free fastbin blocks (smblks):     17
INFO  sas2    - # of mapped regions (hblks):           36
INFO  sas2    - Bytes in mapped regions (hblkhd):      139460608
INFO  sas2    - Max. total allocated space (usmblks):  0
INFO  sas2    - Free bytes held in fastbins (fsmblks): 912
INFO  sas2    - Total allocated space (uordblks):      175712192
INFO  sas2    - Total free space (fordblks):           6035520
INFO  sas2    - Topmost releasable block (keepcost):   60112
```

The stats after processing the event are

```
INFO  sas2    - Total non-mmapped bytes (arena):       181747712
INFO  sas2    - # of free chunks (ordblks):            797
INFO  sas2    - # of free fastbin blocks (smblks):     0
INFO  sas2    - # of mapped regions (hblks):           38
INFO  sas2    - Bytes in mapped regions (hblkhd):      153735168
INFO  sas2    - Max. total allocated space (usmblks):  0
INFO  sas2    - Free bytes held in fastbins (fsmblks): 0
INFO  sas2    - Total allocated space (uordblks):      1056528
INFO  sas2    - Total free space (fordblks):           180691184
INFO  sas2    - Topmost releasable block (keepcost):   238368
```

As you can see, there is almost 180MB of free memory indicated by fordblks. Although the application frees up the memory, malloc doesn't seem to give it back to kernel. Since my system is already memory constrained, I cannot afford to lose such a huge chunk of memory. Is there a way I can forcefully free the bytes indicated by fordblks?

I tried malloc_trim and it didn't help. As you can see, it just frees the "keepcost" bytes.

Comment: same problem. let me know if you solved it somehow